# how to append values to string in java while iterating a list using stream()

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to iterate a list and append values to a StringBuilder in Java 8. I have written the below code which is working but I need to use map/stream etc to iterate the list instead of using a forEach loop.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
list.stream().forEach(r->{
sb.append("t1.").append(r).append("=").append("t2.").append(r).append(" and ");
}
```

I have another list and map where I need to replace a string if list of elements are matching with key of map.

```
List<String> list=Arrays.asList("key1", "key2","key3","key4");
        Map<String, String> map1  = new HashMap<String, String>() ;
        map1.put("key1", "value1");
        map1.put("key2", "value2");
        map1.put("key11", "value11");
        var classVar=new Object() {
            String sb="";
        };
        classVar.sb="Select * from table1 where key1='apple' and key2='mango'";

        list.stream().forEach (e->{
            map1.forEach((k,v)->{
                if(e.equalsIgnoreCase(k)){
                    classVar.sb=classVar.sb.replaceAll(k,v);
                }
            });
        });
```

How to iterate the same using map()/stream() etc functionality of Java 8 instead of a forEach loop?

Comment: do you need the "and" to be appended in the last iteration?

Answer (score 4):

I'd stream the list, map each element to add the equality expression and then join them with the `" and "` string. This will also prevent you from getting the redundant "and" at the end that seems unintentional:

```java
String result = 
    list.stream().map(r -> "t1." + r + "=t2." + r).collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
```

Comment: thanks a ton for your reply. could you please help me in converting the next code also where I need to use java 8 functionality like map(), stream() in place of forEach loop.